# How to control page margin when printing HTML document?

Tags: css, padding

I'm printing a long HTML document and i want to set the margin between the pages in the CSS file.
Unfortunately, the padding/margin only take effect in the first page (padding-top) and the last page (padding-bottom).

Any way to set the margin between pages?

Comment: The @page declaration was in an inner css file in Angluar 2. moving it to the higher styles.css solved it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not *margin between pages* but *page margin*. It's controlled by a specific [CSS media `@page`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page):

```
@page {
    margin: 1cm;
}
```

Please refer to linked specs for all the details (especially about how `@page` combines with, for example, `<body>` margins).

Note that with pseudo-selectors you can control the aspect of `:left`, `:right` and `:first` pages (just to mention few common use cases).

Comment: both chrome and safari on OS X ignore this property. What is the browser support for @page margin?

Comment: Safari does not support it, Chrome does (tested on Windows), Details: http://caniuse.com/#search=%40page Note: please vote to fix this issue in WebKit (links on caniuse), I'd really love to have `@page` supported in my  wkhtmlpdf docs!!! ;)